# How to reinitialise Datatable without destroy()

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to reinitialise a datatable without destroying it. The problem in destroying table is that it reloads the search filters and it gives a flickering effect to the screen.

I just want to reload my table data without re-rendering the searching table size and pagination filters.

```
var table = $('#clinic_List').DataTable({
  "deferRender": true
});

table.destroy();
setTimeout(function () {
  datatable.DataTable.init();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Where and how do you get your data ? What did you tried ? Have you seen this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax ? And this: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() ?

Comment: I am using this in reactjs application so i am no getting data from ajax

Comment: So where do you get the data from? Static table? Javascript?

Comment: no from web api Asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax.reload()

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

or

```
$('#clinic_List').DataTable({"deferRender": true}).ajax.reload();
```

Comment: i am not using ajax calls so i cant use ajax.reload() as it gives me error that can't resolve data of null as ajax . data is undefined

Comment: in the link they have used destroy  i dont want to use destroy

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Datatables API [rows().remove()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()) or [clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear())  to delete and then useing [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) to add the
>   rows required, which is basically what ajax.reload() does, just for
>   all rows.

Finally we use Datatables API [draw(](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())):

> While above API only clear/remove data internally, but that action
>   won't be visually shown until the draw() method is called to update
>   the display. This method can called simply as a chained method.

Datatables API [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) have one (1) parameter to determine what kind of draw DataTables will perform:

**full-reset** or **true** (default)

- `the ordering and search will be recalculated and the rows redrawn in their new positions. The paging will be reset back to the first page`.

**full-hold** or **false**

- `the ordering and search will be recalculated and the rows redrawn in their new positions. The paging will not be reset - i.e. the current page will still be shown`.

**page**

- `ordering and search will not be updated and the paging position held where is was. This is useful for paging (i.e. page()) when data has not been changed between draws`.

> Please note that the string options require DataTables **1.10.8** or
>   newer. Previous versions support only the boolean option.

You can use **table.draw("full-hold")** or **table.draw(false)**, it will redraw the table without resetting search, ordering and paging.

Example:

```
var person = [
    {name:"person1"},
    {name:"person2"},
    {name:"person3"},
    {name:"person4"}
];

// Create table with data set
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: person,
    columns:[
     {"data" :"name"}
    ]
} );

table.clear().rows.add(person).draw(false);
```

> If your data source got changes (example updating columns value) then
>   you can consider to use Datatables API [rows().invalidate()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().invalidate()). Note
>   this not suitable for new data added to data source.  Found sample here [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidhequet/s98e2fqp/)

**Demo clear() and rows.add() method**:

```js
var person = [
    {name:"person1"},
    {name:"person2"},
    {name:"person3"},
    {name:"person4"}
];
 
// Create table with data set
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: person,
    columns:[
     {"data" :"name"}
    ]
});


document.getElementById("create").onclick = function() { addData() }; 
document.getElementById("refresh").onclick = function() { refreshTab() };

function addData() {
  person.push( {name:"new person"} );
} 

function refreshTab() {
 table.clear().rows.add(person).draw(false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="create">Create row</button>
<button id="refresh">Refresh table</button>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a destroy option that can be used to DataTables that you know that it is going to destroy the existing table to apply the new options. This worked for me:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  destroy: true,
  searching: false
} );
```